# Do you know, or is there a way to find out which apps can be disabled or uninstalled without compromising the rest of my Android 5.1.1?

Tags: chrome-for-android

First of all, I thank you for the info from my earlier question. I'm not really having problems, just trying to learn. I have trouble finding answers to specific questions on the web. Now I am having some problems with not having enough room and the general behavior of this Android. There are so many apps that I have absolutely no idea what they are or how they got there. (Also, is there someway to find out what they are without having to go to multiple sites?) By the way, I'm not sure what tags do either, so I just picked one from the list.

Comment: If you have a fast and surefire way to recover (e.g. custom recovery that can back up the whole OS), just trial and error. However, I believe the majority of apps you don't know what to do with are system apps, which you shouldn't touch and won't save you space anyway.

Comment: @AndyYan if we are keeping within Google's oh-so-free-why-do-you-ask(sarcasm) limits, I doubt much damage can be done. Worst case scenario is a factory reset via recovery. Even then, I don't think you can disable system-critixal things like the UI. You can force stop them, but they start right back up.